# minidom.parse reading short XML?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

Here are 2 similar XML files :

**Long XML**

```
<mynode>
   <text>Blah</text>
   <position>322,13</position>
</mynode>
```

**Short XML**

```
<mynode text="Blah" position="322,13" />
```

---

It seems that Python's `minidom.parse` doesn't like the **short XML**.

**Is this *short XML style* available with `minidom` (XML) ?**

**Is it possible to write a unique code that will read both short and long XML ?**

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't like it"? Are you getting an error? Please post your code that parses XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def getChild(n,v):
    for child in n.childNodes:
        if child.localName==v:
            yield child

def getValue(n, val):
    res = None
    for n in mynode:
        rv = getChild(n,val)
        for v in rv:
            var = v.childNodes[0].nodeValue
            res = var
    if not res:
        for n in mynode:
            attr = n.getAttributeNode(val)
            if attr:
                res = attr.nodeValue.strip()

    return res


xmldoc = minidom.parse('file.xml')
mynode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('mynode')
print getValue(mynode,'text')
print getValue(mynode,'position')
```

output:

```
Blah
322,13
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution shows that I have to handle in a **different** way if *long XML code* (`getElementsByTagName('position')`)   and different code if  *short XML code* (`getAttribute('position')`).... Isn't there a way to handle both with the same code ?

Comment: it finds the parent named 'mynode' using getElementsByTagName, from that, it tries to find "attributes" of that particular parent using getAttribute.

Comment: Is there a way for reading the *short XML* and the *long XML* (in my question) with **the same code** ?

Comment: can you please add example for short and long XML?

Comment: I modified the question and have defined what I call "short XML" and "long XML". I also added this question: is it possible to write a unique code that will read both short and long XML ?

Comment: ok..got it..I could come up with new code (edited my answer). It looks for node and it's child as per long xml, if long xml format not found, it looks for short xml format. I have tested with both of your xml format and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need a root node

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
>>> doc = parseString('<root><mynode text="Blah" position="322,13" /></root>')
>>> print d.firstChild.firstChild.getAttribute('text')
Blah
>>> print d.firstChild.firstChild.getAttribute('position')
322,13
```

Comment: Ok so attributes have to be read with "getAttribute"... 
I thought I could get them with `getElementsByTagName('position')`... That's probably the reason of the error I got...